# Show that operator is self-adjoint in $\mu L^2(\mu dv)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.02173.pdf), page 9.

The background of my question is the equation
$$
\partial_tF-\partial_v(\partial_v+v)F=0,\quad F_{|t=0}=F^0,
$$
where $F=F(t,v)$ is unknown for $t>0$.

An equilibrium is given by
$$
\mu(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{-v^2/2}.
$$

Now consider $F(t,\cdot)\in\mu L^2(\mu \,\mathrm dv)$, where $\mu \,\mathrm dv=\mu(v) \,\mathrm dv$.

It is said on page 9 (five lines after $(13)$) that the operator $L=-\partial_v (\partial_v+v)$ is **self-adjoint in $\mu L^2(\mu \,\mathrm dv)$**.

Why? I do not see that.

---

I think my problem dates back to the problem that I do not understand what is meant by the function space $\mu L^2(\mu\,\mathrm  dv)$ and, in particular, its inner product.

Intuitively, I think the inner product is supposed to be something like
$$
\langle f,g\rangle_{\mu L^2(\mu dv)}=\mu(v)\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\,g\,\mu\,\mathrm  dv
$$
but I am really not sure if this makes any sense; at least, using this definition, my computations did not show
$$
\langle Lf,g\rangle_{\mu L^2(\mu dv)}=\langle f,Lg\rangle_{\mu L^2(\mu dv)}.
$$

**EDIT**

Supposing that it's a typo and $L^2(\mu\, dv)$ is meant, i.e.,
$$
\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fg\, \mu\, dv,
$$
I get
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Lf,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)} &= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f_{vv}g+fg+v f_v g)\, \mu\, dv\\
&=-\left(\overbrace{\int f_{vv}g\,\mu\, dv}^{=:A}+\overbrace{\int fg\,\mu\, dv}^{=:B}+\overbrace{\int f_v v g\,\mu\, dv}^{=:C}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
and then by several integrations by part,
$$
\begin{align*}
A&=\langle f,g_{vv}-g-v^2g\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}\\
B&=\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}\\
C&=\langle f,-g-v g_v+v^2g\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}
\end{align*}
$$
so that
$$
A+B+C=\langle f,g_{vv}-g,-vg_v\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Lf,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}&=-(A+B+C)\\
&=\langle f,-g_{vv}+g+vg_v\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}\\
&\neq\langle f,-g_{vv}-g-vg_v\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}\\
&=\langle f,Lg\rangle_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: As you note, this is a difficult question to approach without a definition of "$\mu L^2 (\mu \, d\nu)$" (at least, I do not recognize this notation).  Depending on that, it may also help to provide clarity about the domain of $L$ (i.e. when one says self adjoint "in $\mu L^2 (\mu \, d\nu)$" (whatever that is), do we mean the whole space "$\mu L^2  (\mu d\nu)$" (whatever that is), or some particular dense subspace that is related to how $L$ is defined. (It may also be helpful to mention if you have use of any background results in that would guarantee self-adjointness under __ hypotheses)

Comment: Yes, what does the prefix $\mu$ on $\muL^2(\mu\,dv)$ mean? You've got $\mu$ in the measure, already, ... Please clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. At the beginning of my question, I added the source where I found this. However, I cannot get what the meaning of the notation is supposed to mean.

Comment: @MarsPlastic You suggest that it is a typo and they mean $L^2(\mu\, dv)$ instead? But then I get $\langle Lf,g\rangle\neq\langle f,Lg\rangle$ (please see my edit in my original question).

Comment: @selector You're right, I misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems indeed to be an unclear and undefined notation of the paper.

I suppose it means the following
$$
\mu \,L^2(\mu\,\mathrm d v) = \{g = \mu\,f: f\in L^2(\mu\,\mathrm d v)\}
$$
and so I would expect that
$$
\|g\|_{\mu \,L^2(\mu\,\mathrm d v)}^2 = \|g/\mu\|_{L^2(\mu\,\mathrm d v)}^2 = \int |g|^2\,\mu^{-1}\,\mathrm d v.
\\
\langle f,g\rangle_{\mu \,L^2(\mu\,\mathrm d v)} = \int f\,g\,\mu^{-1}\,\mathrm d v.
$$
Then since $\partial_v\mu(v)^{-1} = v\,\mu(v)^{-1}$,
$$
\langle Lf,g\rangle_{\mu \,L^2(\mu\,\mathrm d v)} = -\int \partial_v(\partial_v+v)f\,g\,\mu^{-1}\,\mathrm d v
\\
= \int (\partial_v+v)f\,\partial_v(g\,\mu^{-1})\,\mathrm d v
\\
= \int (\partial_v+v)f\,(\partial_v+v)g\,\mu^{-1}\,\mathrm d v = \langle f,Lg\rangle_{\mu \,L^2(\mu\,\mathrm d v)}
$$
so $L^*=L$.

Comment: That may be correct. At least, as suggested in one comment, if this is a typo and $L^2(\mu\, dv)$ is meant instead, I get that $\langle Lf,g\rangle\neq\langle f,Lg\rangle$ as I edited in my original question. - So, it seems to be no typo (if my computations are correct) and this really seems to have a meaning. Maybe the one you suggest.